# Lift w/Redis examples

Tags: scala, redis, lift, jedis

I've been playing around with Redis and Scala separately, and thought it'd be neat to combine them in a simple Lift app.

I've done a fair bit of Googling and can't find any examples of a Lift app that uses Redis.  Is there a reason for this?

What drivers/APIs do you recommend for using Redis w/Lift?  I'm currently working with Jedis (https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis).

Comment: In general, you can use any Java library to connect to protocols and services. Scala compiles to the same kind of JVM classes as Java does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use scalatra with jedis as the connector to redis, works fine as well. Java data types will be converted to equivalents in scala implicitly when scala.collection.JavaConversions._ is imported (in scala 2.8 or later). To use jedis, simply add this line to your project definition file in sbt 0.7.x:

```
val jedis = "redis.clients" % "jedis" % "2.0.0"
```

or this in sbt 0.10.x:

```
libraryDependencies += "redis.clients" % "jedis" % "2.0.0"
```

Comment: Thanks. For me (sbt 0.10.1, scala 2.9.0-1), `"redis.clients" %% "jedis" % "2.0.0"` failed but `"redis.clients" % "jedis" % "2.0.0"` worked.  What's the difference between `%%` and `%`?

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped. Yes, it should be one % instead, double % means that the library would be cross built, sbt will find the correct version of that library that matches the local scala version. [This page](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Cross-Build) gives more details on cross building.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested a couple of scala redis connectors - settled on https://github.com/debasishg/scala-redis for further testing.

Simply

> val scalaredis = "net.debasishg" % "redisclient_2.9.0" % "2.3.1"

in SBT

Answer (score 0):

According to http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.debasishg/redisclient_2.9.1,

```
libraryDependencies += "net.debasishg" %% "redisclient" % "2.7"
```